# How to remove the extra lines between the items in the enumerate environment and to prevent the alignement of the text

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

Currently the output of the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}%
\setlist[enumerate]{label={\upshape(\roman*)},leftmargin=0,  itemindent=*, labelwidth=1,  labelsep=0, align=left}
\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
  \item one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one 
  \item two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two 
  \item three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three
  \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

is as below

```
(i)   one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one
one one one one 

(ii)  two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two
two two two two two two two two two two two two two

(iii) three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three
```

I would like that the text is not being aligned and there is no separating extra lines between the items, i.e., I would like the text appears like this:

```
(i) one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one
one one one one     
(ii) two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two
two two two two two two two two two two two two two    
(iii) three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three
```

In a nutshell, I would like that the items appear like ordinary lines.

Comment: It does not work, there is still an extra line between the items.

Comment: Sorry, meant `[noitemsep]` or `[nosep]`. `nolistsep` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks this resolves the issue with the extra lines, but the text is still aligned, i.e, one, two, and three are at the same horizontal position.

Comment: Yes I exactly applied `\setlist[enumerate]{label={\upshape(\roman*)},leftmargin=0mm, itemindent=*,labelw‌​idth=!,align=left,nosep} `.

Comment: Try `\setlist[enumerate]{label={\upshape(\roman*)},leftmargin=0pt,labelwidth=*,align=left,nosep}`

Comment: If you like,  consider to convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: There, done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all `enumerate` environments like this, you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for demo text only

\setlist[enumerate]{
  label={\upshape(\roman*)},
  leftmargin=0pt‌​,
  labelwidth=*,
  align=‌​left,
  nosep
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]
\begin{enumerate}
  \item one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one 
  \item two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two 
  \item three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

> [image: Output]

The way this works with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

- `leftmargin=0pt` makes sure the items aren't indented on the line.
- `labelwidth=*` means that the labelwidth is set to the width of the current label, i.e. it is not necessarily the same for every item.
- `align=left` makes the labels aligned to the left
- `nosep` is the same as writing `partopsep=0pt, topsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt` with less keystrokes. Internally the `nosep` key is defined as

  ```
  \enitkv@key{enumitem}{nosep}[true]{%
    \partopsep=\z@skip
    \topsep=\z@skip
    \itemsep=\z@skip
    \parsep=\z@skip}
  ```

  Optionally one can use `noitemsep`, which sets `itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt` if one wants more space before the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see the separation above an below the list is determined by `topsep` and `partopsep` so setting them both to `0pt` removes the space outside the list. The space between items is determined by `parsep` and `itemsep` so they should also be `0pt`. If you want the items to really work as ordinary lines I guess they should be indented like paragraphs, which you can get by `labelindent=\parindent`. To remove the horizontal alignment set `labelwidth=*`, but then you also want some extra space after the label, `labelsep=1em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}%
\setlist[enumerate]{%
  label={\upshape(\roman*)},
  leftmargin=0pt,  
  itemindent=*, 
  labelwidth=*,  
  labelsep=1em, 
  align=left,
  topsep=0pt,
  partopsep=0pt,
  parsep=0pt,
  itemsep=0pt,
  % labelindent=\parindent,
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}
\item one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one 
\item two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two 
\item three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three three
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this solves the issue with extra lines between the items. But there are two issues with this, (1) the text is still aligned, i.e., one, two and three are at the same horizontal position. (2) there is an indent before (i), (ii) and (iii), in my original setting I had resolved this.

Comment: I have made an edit to remove the horizontal alignment. To remove the extra indentation just remove `labelindent=\parindent`.

Comment: I have also removed the extra indentation. To me that looks like a newline within the paragraph, which I try to avoid. It should be either new paragraph or no line break. But since it is a list it might work.

Comment: Thank you, just an issue, the space between `(i)` and `one` is more than an ordinary space. I guess  `labelsep=1em` controls this. Is it possible to change this in order to obtain exactly an ordinary space.

Comment: I realized that commenting this out can solve the issue.

Comment: Commenting out works pretty good. I don't think you can get exactly the same as inter-word space since this changes depending on the text (a rubberband space). I would guess you get a little bit closer with `labelsep=\the\fontdimen2\font`.